# Incorrect characters displayed for Tamil font in android(Latha.ttf)

Tags: android, fonts, textview, tamil, typeface

I need to use tamil on textviews in my app so I create a TypeFace from
assets and set it to the textview, but the characters appear out of order(mixed) for combined characters. I load the strings from the resources.(string.xml in utf-8 encoding)
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Im also looking to support hindi and tamil fonts in my app. as they're the core features of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently android does not have a tamil font Shaping Engine. So have to manually reorder the characters based on the tamil language rules.

Answer (score 1):

use fonts like "Bamini.ttf" else some TSCII fonts. It works fine for me. It should work for you too.